# Hide footer on independent column scroll down, appear on scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm working on creating a two-column website; the two columns scroll independently. I need the footer to be hidden when the user scrolls down and to appear again once the user scrolls back up. I'm new to Javascript and I recently learned how to do this with a site that scrolls as a whole. I've already browsed through questions of that nature here too, however I'm having trouble trying to apply that to the independent columns. I got the footer to hide on scroll down of the left column, but I can't get it to reappear when scrolling up. I've put together an example of what I have. Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
var prevScrollpos = document.getElementById("left").pageYOffset;
document.getElementById("left").onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.bottom = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.bottom = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgreen;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-top: 9px solid #f8f25c;
}

p{
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 25px;    
}

#content, html, body {
    height: 99%;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #fdfef9;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: #4668ff;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: orangered;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: bottom 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <div id="left">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vestibulum venenatis purus, id viverra ante laoreet quis. Cras varius, quam at lacinia mollis, tellus massa vulputate ante, at maximus lacus erat in ex. Fusce at suscipit diam, in laoreet neque. Sed aliquam vel dui quis maximus. Nullam ultricies a nisl in consequat. Duis viverra arcu eu ultrices egestas. Duis lacinia leo a velit vehicula, in vestibulum lorem commodo. Duis id ipsum ut libero egestas blandit. Pellentesque ac magna tortor. Vivamus at ornare eros. Suspendisse interdum purus et turpis finibus, quis viverra nulla ultricies.</p>

<p>Nulla ultrices efficitur mi. Aenean facilisis lorem rhoncus dapibus consectetur. Quisque volutpat ipsum enim. Phasellus eros erat, pulvinar vel nibh tincidunt, tincidunt porta augue. Nullam aliquet at ante in ornare. Maecenas et bibendum dui, nec consectetur elit. Sed et elit vel mauris tempor facilisis. Vestibulum sed rhoncus nunc. Cras in orci condimentum, ultricies nulla eu, semper nisl. Sed dignissim nisl a pellentesque euismod. Suspendisse ut nunc a tortor mollis condimentum. Mauris sodales dolor et justo sagittis, quis euismod nunc consectetur. Nunc et condimentum nibh, non viverra risus. Aliquam facilisis mauris vitae quam fringilla interdum.</p>

<p>Morbi porta erat odio, cursus aliquam ipsum feugiat sed. Vivamus rhoncus vitae nisi in pellentesque. Donec eu diam felis. Sed dignissim euismod sem placerat porta. Integer dictum euismod nulla, non lobortis magna fermentum non. Ut et quam libero. Suspendisse at eros nec sapien tempus ornare. Nam pretium vestibulum enim quis congue. Integer in mi tincidunt, imperdiet tellus bibendum, efficitur sem. Aenean suscipit sapien quis erat accumsan congue. Cras finibus, mauris eget sollicitudin consequat, risus mauris placerat nulla, at malesuada erat ipsum vel nibh.</p>

<p>Sed malesuada rhoncus ante, non pellentesque leo lobortis quis. Integer fringilla ut erat sit amet ullamcorper. Nulla eu ultricies eros. Etiam et sollicitudin massa, sit amet finibus turpis. Duis justo sapien, volutpat eget sagittis id, hendrerit sit amet dui. Vivamus arcu dui, ultrices id interdum non, mattis id elit. Phasellus ultrices posuere nisi, at tempor eros accumsan nec. Quisque sem augue, venenatis vitae nunc non, lacinia pharetra mauris. Nullam tempor at ex in tincidunt. Morbi lobortis, ipsum in placerat interdum, metus justo vehicula lectus, vel molestie metus mi ut massa. Sed posuere ligula eget neque convallis varius.</p>

<p>Aenean imperdiet neque pulvinar dolor vestibulum aliquet. Morbi posuere odio eu condimentum consequat. Quisque dignissim lorem quis nulla vulputate, in consectetur arcu commodo. Nunc eros ex, volutpat in varius sed, semper sed turpis. Mauris vitae dictum augue. Maecenas ullamcorper mauris ante, id posuere mi viverra in. Phasellus sed vehicula orci, non venenatis libero. Fusce vehicula pretium gravida. Quisque semper nunc ac arcu tristique, eget consequat tortor blandit. Proin ut lobortis dolor. Ut placerat at leo vitae tincidunt. Pellentesque ac iaculis lorem. Fusce ut mauris metus. Integer nulla purus, vestibulum id maximus sit amet, aliquet non arcu.</p>

<p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus ultricies placerat magna, sed euismod tellus ultrices ac. Nam id nunc nibh. Integer elementum dui ac tincidunt pulvinar. Integer et est a leo condimentum pulvinar vitae eget orci. Etiam lobortis neque ut tortor tincidunt, eget condimentum velit lacinia. Quisque vel semper velit. Mauris vitae rutrum libero. Phasellus varius nunc nunc, elementum viverra libero rutrum vel. Mauris vitae ex tempor, gravida sem vel, aliquam dui. Mauris ac eleifend neque. Pellentesque eget nulla egestas, tempus massa eget, suscipit neque. Proin sed ligula vel sem rutrum ullamcorper.</p>

<p>Duis eleifend nisl in lectus commodo pharetra. Fusce varius rhoncus semper. Aliquam pellentesque nisl ac orci feugiat, in finibus nibh aliquam. In nec augue vulputate, lobortis nibh ut, consequat augue. Suspendisse sodales enim ac libero finibus fermentum. Curabitur fermentum augue ante, eget pharetra leo dictum at. Sed sapien lacus, bibendum egestas malesuada eget, malesuada nec lectus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus elementum, diam sagittis viverra placerat, diam ante finibus tellus, id feugiat metus lacus in nunc. Nulla imperdiet magna ante, vel volutpat ligula vehicula id. Maecenas et urna massa. Quisque justo quam, tincidunt ac orci at, accumsan volutpat nunc. Pellentesque sem elit, consectetur placerat orci vel, dignissim auctor nulla. Aenean quis dui non odio consectetur sagittis sed nec sapien. Maecenas cursus at quam sed cursus. Aenean tristique odio neque, quis pharetra ipsum blandit eu. Fusce porttitor lacinia quam et vehicula.</p>

<p>Maecenas viverra dolor nisl, sed interdum massa consequat condimentum. Morbi ultrices tellus enim, ac consectetur enim viverra non. Aenean vestibulum vestibulum dolor, id auctor sem placerat vel. Quisque sed ligula ac lorem maximus consectetur nec eu mi. Integer ut felis vitae lorem commodo euismod eget non orci. Nam eleifend tempus lacinia. Donec ac odio non dolor laoreet facilisis. Vivamus blandit venenatis velit sed venenatis. Morbi porttitor efficitur justo, ac varius urna tincidunt interdum. In commodo lorem in nunc placerat sodales nec a velit. Nunc vitae sodales nisl, eget lobortis sem. Nulla in est pretium dolor sollicitudin pulvinar sed nec mi. Phasellus lobortis dui viverra vulputate eleifend. Ut tempus nibh scelerisque, mollis erat sit amet, auctor felis.</p>

<p>Donec tempor sed lorem sed molestie. Nulla facilisi. Donec luctus enim vitae ante vulputate tincidunt. Vestibulum urna leo, egestas sollicitudin nisi et, cursus tristique nulla. Nunc commodo arcu ut dui tincidunt rutrum. Mauris volutpat, leo eget feugiat molestie, ipsum lectus lobortis nibh, nec pellentesque lorem nulla consectetur metus. Nunc condimentum enim eros, sit amet tempor turpis elementum in. Nunc et magna vel augue sagittis ullamcorper.</p>

<p>Nam venenatis ac nibh et hendrerit. Nam nulla nunc, dapibus mollis laoreet sed, lobortis laoreet nisi. Ut sed porttitor felis. Vivamus eget eros velit. Suspendisse porta neque libero, ut placerat metus malesuada et. Cras dictum pharetra ullamcorper. Duis ultrices elit semper, fermentum velit vel, hendrerit massa. Morbi at condimentum erat. Nulla lorem justo, condimentum eu congue eget, vehicula eget mauris. Pellentesque ut nisl at ante molestie ornare in non diam.</p>

<p>Cras feugiat feugiat orci, sed consequat magna ultrices vel. Suspendisse porttitor vulputate ante. Fusce nisl quam, rutrum et odio nec, dapibus porta ligula. Nullam pharetra enim non erat fermentum ultricies. Nam ultrices, ligula et vestibulum ullamcorper, mauris velit rhoncus arcu, sed tempus est ante vel ligula. Proin vitae lacinia erat, ut varius enim. Suspendisse et turpis est. Nulla facilisi. Quisque porttitor vel odio cursus varius. Mauris ac sem purus. Ut ut dignissim diam. Praesent ultricies porta nunc. Vivamus interdum porttitor tellus, quis volutpat eros pharetra vel. Vestibulum vehicula arcu dictum condimentum condimentum. Duis dapibus nunc lectus, sit amet volutpat ipsum finibus commodo. Suspendisse mauris mi, consequat ut aliquet in, laoreet non odio.</p>

<p>Pellentesque lobortis dui nec cursus sollicitudin. Ut fermentum varius purus ut rutrum. Duis at ante sed purus lobortis blandit quis vel massa. Integer a augue semper, consectetur mi eu, luctus risus. Aenean volutpat efficitur aliquet. Proin eu mauris eu odio fermentum sodales. Integer mollis varius ligula et rhoncus. Quisque nec dolor vitae arcu mollis varius eu mollis justo. Pellentesque sagittis leo vitae ipsum ullamcorper, at pulvinar nisl feugiat. Cras ullamcorper ex sed condimentum suscipit. Donec mollis suscipit nunc aliquam malesuada. Nulla interdum commodo quam, a ullamcorper tellus condimentum sit amet. Maecenas purus justo, molestie porta vestibulum luctus, fringilla et erat.</p>

<p>Fusce eu eros eget eros dictum interdum. Aliquam non arcu non risus consequat efficitur. Nam elementum sollicitudin placerat. Aliquam ac massa eu nibh tristique varius quis at diam. Praesent at diam elementum, tristique turpis in, finibus lorem. Ut et dolor mattis, dignissim nulla sed, semper lacus. Cras sit amet elementum arcu, a consectetur risus. Donec id magna sapien. Sed dui nibh, rutrum nec ultrices ut, convallis eu ligula. Nulla sagittis ullamcorper massa et ultrices. Maecenas ut lorem vitae nunc aliquam finibus et sed quam. Pellentesque cursus vel arcu ac faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque faucibus vitae orci vitae sodales. Mauris non laoreet nisi. Fusce nulla quam, feugiat ac odio vitae, congue pulvinar ligula.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse vestibulum venenatis purus, id viverra ante laoreet quis. Cras varius, quam at lacinia mollis, tellus massa vulputate ante, at maximus lacus erat in ex. Fusce at suscipit diam, in laoreet neque. Sed aliquam vel dui quis maximus. Nullam ultricies a nisl in consequat. Duis viverra arcu eu ultrices egestas. Duis lacinia leo a velit vehicula, in vestibulum lorem commodo. Duis id ipsum ut libero egestas blandit. Pellentesque ac magna tortor. Vivamus at ornare eros. Suspendisse interdum purus et turpis finibus, quis viverra nulla ultricies.</p>

<p>Nulla ultrices efficitur mi. Aenean facilisis lorem rhoncus dapibus consectetur. Quisque volutpat ipsum enim. Phasellus eros erat, pulvinar vel nibh tincidunt, tincidunt porta augue. Nullam aliquet at ante in ornare. Maecenas et bibendum dui, nec consectetur elit. Sed et elit vel mauris tempor facilisis. Vestibulum sed rhoncus nunc. Cras in orci condimentum, ultricies nulla eu, semper nisl. Sed dignissim nisl a pellentesque euismod. Suspendisse ut nunc a tortor mollis condimentum. Mauris sodales dolor et justo sagittis, quis euismod nunc consectetur. Nunc et condimentum nibh, non viverra risus. Aliquam facilisis mauris vitae quam fringilla interdum.</p>

<p>Morbi porta erat odio, cursus aliquam ipsum feugiat sed. Vivamus rhoncus vitae nisi in pellentesque. Donec eu diam felis. Sed dignissim euismod sem placerat porta. Integer dictum euismod nulla, non lobortis magna fermentum non. Ut et quam libero. Suspendisse at eros nec sapien tempus ornare. Nam pretium vestibulum enim quis congue. Integer in mi tincidunt, imperdiet tellus bibendum, efficitur sem. Aenean suscipit sapien quis erat accumsan congue. Cras finibus, mauris eget sollicitudin consequat, risus mauris placerat nulla, at malesuada erat ipsum vel nibh.</p>

<p>Sed malesuada rhoncus ante, non pellentesque leo lobortis quis. Integer fringilla ut erat sit amet ullamcorper. Nulla eu ultricies eros. Etiam et sollicitudin massa, sit amet finibus turpis. Duis justo sapien, volutpat eget sagittis id, hendrerit sit amet dui. Vivamus arcu dui, ultrices id interdum non, mattis id elit. Phasellus ultrices posuere nisi, at tempor eros accumsan nec. Quisque sem augue, venenatis vitae nunc non, lacinia pharetra mauris. Nullam tempor at ex in tincidunt. Morbi lobortis, ipsum in placerat interdum, metus justo vehicula lectus, vel molestie metus mi ut massa. Sed posuere ligula eget neque convallis varius.</p>

<p>Aenean imperdiet neque pulvinar dolor vestibulum aliquet. Morbi posuere odio eu condimentum consequat. Quisque dignissim lorem quis nulla vulputate, in consectetur arcu commodo. Nunc eros ex, volutpat in varius sed, semper sed turpis. Mauris vitae dictum augue. Maecenas ullamcorper mauris ante, id posuere mi viverra in. Phasellus sed vehicula orci, non venenatis libero. Fusce vehicula pretium gravida. Quisque semper nunc ac arcu tristique, eget consequat tortor blandit. Proin ut lobortis dolor. Ut placerat at leo vitae tincidunt. Pellentesque ac iaculis lorem. Fusce ut mauris metus. Integer nulla purus, vestibulum id maximus sit amet, aliquet non arcu.</p>

<p>Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vivamus ultricies placerat magna, sed euismod tellus ultrices ac. Nam id nunc nibh. Integer elementum dui ac tincidunt pulvinar. Integer et est a leo condimentum pulvinar vitae eget orci. Etiam lobortis neque ut tortor tincidunt, eget condimentum velit lacinia. Quisque vel semper velit. Mauris vitae rutrum libero. Phasellus varius nunc nunc, elementum viverra libero rutrum vel. Mauris vitae ex tempor, gravida sem vel, aliquam dui. Mauris ac eleifend neque. Pellentesque eget nulla egestas, tempus massa eget, suscipit neque. Proin sed ligula vel sem rutrum ullamcorper.</p>

<p>Duis eleifend nisl in lectus commodo pharetra. Fusce varius rhoncus semper. Aliquam pellentesque nisl ac orci feugiat, in finibus nibh aliquam. In nec augue vulputate, lobortis nibh ut, consequat augue. Suspendisse sodales enim ac libero finibus fermentum. Curabitur fermentum augue ante, eget pharetra leo dictum at. Sed sapien lacus, bibendum egestas malesuada eget, malesuada nec lectus.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus elementum, diam sagittis viverra placerat, diam ante finibus tellus, id feugiat metus lacus in nunc. Nulla imperdiet magna ante, vel volutpat ligula vehicula id. Maecenas et urna massa. Quisque justo quam, tincidunt ac orci at, accumsan volutpat nunc. Pellentesque sem elit, consectetur placerat orci vel, dignissim auctor nulla. Aenean quis dui non odio consectetur sagittis sed nec sapien. Maecenas cursus at quam sed cursus. Aenean tristique odio neque, quis pharetra ipsum blandit eu. Fusce porttitor lacinia quam et vehicula.</p>

<p>Maecenas viverra dolor nisl, sed interdum massa consequat condimentum. Morbi ultrices tellus enim, ac consectetur enim viverra non. Aenean vestibulum vestibulum dolor, id auctor sem placerat vel. Quisque sed ligula ac lorem maximus consectetur nec eu mi. Integer ut felis vitae lorem commodo euismod eget non orci. Nam eleifend tempus lacinia. Donec ac odio non dolor laoreet facilisis. Vivamus blandit venenatis velit sed venenatis. Morbi porttitor efficitur justo, ac varius urna tincidunt interdum. In commodo lorem in nunc placerat sodales nec a velit. Nunc vitae sodales nisl, eget lobortis sem. Nulla in est pretium dolor sollicitudin pulvinar sed nec mi. Phasellus lobortis dui viverra vulputate eleifend. Ut tempus nibh scelerisque, mollis erat sit amet, auctor felis.</p>

<p>Donec tempor sed lorem sed molestie. Nulla facilisi. Donec luctus enim vitae ante vulputate tincidunt. Vestibulum urna leo, egestas sollicitudin nisi et, cursus tristique nulla. Nunc commodo arcu ut dui tincidunt rutrum. Mauris volutpat, leo eget feugiat molestie, ipsum lectus lobortis nibh, nec pellentesque lorem nulla consectetur metus. Nunc condimentum enim eros, sit amet tempor turpis elementum in. Nunc et magna vel augue sagittis ullamcorper.</p>

<p>Nam venenatis ac nibh et hendrerit. Nam nulla nunc, dapibus mollis laoreet sed, lobortis laoreet nisi. Ut sed porttitor felis. Vivamus eget eros velit. Suspendisse porta neque libero, ut placerat metus malesuada et. Cras dictum pharetra ullamcorper. Duis ultrices elit semper, fermentum velit vel, hendrerit massa. Morbi at condimentum erat. Nulla lorem justo, condimentum eu congue eget, vehicula eget mauris. Pellentesque ut nisl at ante molestie ornare in non diam.</p>

<p>Cras feugiat feugiat orci, sed consequat magna ultrices vel. Suspendisse porttitor vulputate ante. Fusce nisl quam, rutrum et odio nec, dapibus porta ligula. Nullam pharetra enim non erat fermentum ultricies. Nam ultrices, ligula et vestibulum ullamcorper, mauris velit rhoncus arcu, sed tempus est ante vel ligula. Proin vitae lacinia erat, ut varius enim. Suspendisse et turpis est. Nulla facilisi. Quisque porttitor vel odio cursus varius. Mauris ac sem purus. Ut ut dignissim diam. Praesent ultricies porta nunc. Vivamus interdum porttitor tellus, quis volutpat eros pharetra vel. Vestibulum vehicula arcu dictum condimentum condimentum. Duis dapibus nunc lectus, sit amet volutpat ipsum finibus commodo. Suspendisse mauris mi, consequat ut aliquet in, laoreet non odio.</p>

<p>Pellentesque lobortis dui nec cursus sollicitudin. Ut fermentum varius purus ut rutrum. Duis at ante sed purus lobortis blandit quis vel massa. Integer a augue semper, consectetur mi eu, luctus risus. Aenean volutpat efficitur aliquet. Proin eu mauris eu odio fermentum sodales. Integer mollis varius ligula et rhoncus. Quisque nec dolor vitae arcu mollis varius eu mollis justo. Pellentesque sagittis leo vitae ipsum ullamcorper, at pulvinar nisl feugiat. Cras ullamcorper ex sed condimentum suscipit. Donec mollis suscipit nunc aliquam malesuada. Nulla interdum commodo quam, a ullamcorper tellus condimentum sit amet. Maecenas purus justo, molestie porta vestibulum luctus, fringilla et erat.</p>

<p>Fusce eu eros eget eros dictum interdum. Aliquam non arcu non risus consequat efficitur. Nam elementum sollicitudin placerat. Aliquam ac massa eu nibh tristique varius quis at diam. Praesent at diam elementum, tristique turpis in, finibus lorem. Ut et dolor mattis, dignissim nulla sed, semper lacus. Cras sit amet elementum arcu, a consectetur risus. Donec id magna sapien. Sed dui nibh, rutrum nec ultrices ut, convallis eu ligula. Nulla sagittis ullamcorper massa et ultrices. Maecenas ut lorem vitae nunc aliquam finibus et sed quam. Pellentesque cursus vel arcu ac faucibus. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque faucibus vitae orci vitae sodales. Mauris non laoreet nisi. Fusce nulla quam, feugiat ac odio vitae, congue pulvinar ligula.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var prevScrollpos = document.getElementById("left").scrollTop;
document.getElementById("left").onscroll = function () {
    var currentScrollPos = document.getElementById("left").scrollTop;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.bottom = "0";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.bottom = "-50px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```